# Cannot install cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy, proj

I am using PyCharm IDE and am unable to install 'cartopy'.
When I run the command `pip install cartopy' in the PyCharm terminal I receive the following error message:

```
Collecting cartopy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/92/fe8838fa8158931906dfc4f16c5c1436b3dd2daf83592645b179581403ad/Cartopy-0.17.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  Complete output from command f:\python\python.exe f:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel C:\Users\sagar\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzriwmmff:
  setup.py:171: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.3.3 or later installed, or installation may fail.
    '.'.join(str(v) for v in GEOS_MIN_VERSION), ))
  Proj 4.9.0 must be installed.

  ----------------------------------------
Command "f:\python\python.exe f:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzriwmmff" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-npt9snvs\cartopy
```

Comment: Do you have GEOS installed and what version?  https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/

Comment: I have installed it on windows from https://proj4.org/install.html#install

Comment: Check GEOS version, or install latest one

Comment: How to check this?

Comment: The installed GEOS does not seem to be connecting to cartopy with a pip install. You may have to install cartopy from source or use conda + conda-forge in PyCharm. You may want to try to put GEOS in your path manually then try a pip install   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

Cartopy documentation recommends using Conda ([link](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html#conda-pre-built-binaries)):

```
conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```

Installing it using pip is also possible, but since Cartopy has a bunch of non-Python dependencies (like Proj and GEOS), you'll have to install those separately. That's a hassle and it's easy to end up with errors like the one above. Conda on the other hand can also take care of those non-Python dependencies for you.